# SilverStripe Display Logic for ListboxField not working

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

SilverStripe: v4 
Module used: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic

Hello and good day!

I'm in the Security page (Lists of Members) and was trying to display a ListboxField upon a certain string or value is found on another ListboxField.

[image: Security Page].

With The image above, I wanted to select or input in the **Groups** field the **Sales Representative** role, and once the **Sales Representative** is present in the **Groups**, that's the moment I shall display another field

Here's my code snippet

```
$codesList = Member::get()->column('Code');
$codes = ListboxField::create(
    'AccountPurchases',
    'Account Purchases',
    $codesList);
$fields->insertAfter('DirectGroups', $codes);

$codes->displayIf("DirectGroups")->contains("Sales Representative");
```

But the problem is, no matter what I did (1: dev/build?flush=1, 2: refresh the page, 3: restart the app) the desired field named `$codes` still won't appear.

[image: After Placing Sales Representative]

But if I'm applying it to a normal field like the FirstName (which is a simple TextField), it's working perfectly fine...

```
$codesList = Member::get()->column('Code');
$codes = ListboxField::create(
    'AccountPurchases',
    'Account Purchases',
    $codesList);
$fields->insertAfter('DirectGroups', $codes);

$codes->displayIf("FirstName")->contains("Sales Representative");
```

[image: Fin]

Any ideas how to perform my desired output?

Answer (score 2):

For non-standard form fields, you'll need to use the display-logic wrapper. https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic#dealing-with-non-standard-form-fields

The definition of "non-standard" is a bit hard to find, but in my experience it's anything non-plain-html-input. Listbox is a fancy front-end thing, so it qualifies. The examples in the docs can be confusing, but if you are using SS4 and the latest display-logic, then use `Wrapper::create` instead of `DisplayLogicWrapper::create`. If you wrap it, it should work.

```
$codesList = Member::get()->column('Code');
$codes = Wrapper::create(
    ListboxField::create('AccountPurchases','Account Purchases',$codesList);
)->displayIf("DirectGroups")->contains("Sales Representative")->end();

$fields->insertAfter('DirectGroups', $codes);
```

Comment: hello sir! first of all, I would like to thank you for giving a feedback regarding me query! Now, when I tried the code snipper above, it's giving me the error `Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Object->__call(): extra method getName is invalid on UncleCheese\DisplayLogic\Criteria` are you familiar with this? yes I'm in SS4 so been only using `Wrapper`

Comment: hello sir @blueskies79?

Comment: I'm not a sir ;-)  I might have forgotten an ->end() at the end of the Wrapper statement. I've edited my answer above. Will that help?